# compare two arraylists and get position of common elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylists and the second one is a subset of the first.
I want to know the initial and final position in the first arraylist of elements in the subset (in my example the position in arrayList of: uno, due, tre)

How to modify this code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConfrontaArrayList {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> subSetArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    arrayList.add("inizio");
    arrayList.add("stringa");
    arrayList.add("uno");
    arrayList.add("due");
    arrayList.add("tre");
    arrayList.add("fine");
    arrayList.add("stringa");

    subSetArrayList.add("uno");
    subSetArrayList.add("due");
    subSetArrayList.add("tre");

    System.out.print("Elementi di arrayList: ");
    for (String stringa : arrayList) System.out.print(stringa + " ");
    System.out.print("\nElementi di subSetArrayList: ");
    for (String stringa : subSetArrayList) System.out.print(stringa + " ");
}
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: is only a semplified example to understood how to manage this kind of situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Collections.indexOfSubList()` method will return the index of the sub list:

```
int startIdx = Collections.indexOfSubList(arrayList, subSetArrayList);
if (-1 != startIdx)
{
    int endIdx = startIdx + subSetArrayList.size() - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do the whole problem break it down into smaller steps that you can do:

1. How do you tell if two elements match?
2. Given 1, how do you tell if two equal-length lists match?
3. Given 2, how do you tell if a list matches at a given index in a longer list?
4. Given 3, how can you answer your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is of course to iterate over the arraylist and do a String.equals() to find the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method of ArrayList.

```
for(String item : subSetArrayList)
{
    int index = arrayList.indexOf(item);
}
```

On 2nd thought, if `SubsetArrayList` items are in same sequence and in contigous order. you can do as following:

```
int startIndex = arrayList.indexOf(subSetArrayList.get(0));
int endIndex = startIndex + subSetArrayList.size() - 1;
```

Comment: what do you mean by complete cycle? you are getting the indexes of each element.

Comment: excuse me for my english, I meant "can u write the complete solution?"